# display: none in a for loop and its affect on reflow

Tags: javascript, css, reflow

I was reading through some code today and came across this for loop:

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++){
    document.getElementById(elem + i).style.display="none";
}
```

I've only just begun to learn about browser reflow; However, my current understanding is that this loop is causing a reflow for each of the 100 elements it is setting to display none.

What are the effects of this loop on the DOM? Is this really as horrible as I think it is?

This code is used while rending a new page.

Comment: It does send shivers down my spine— but are you sure it isn't wrapped in a function passed to `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: The effects are that the 100 elements will be hidden. And it depends on the behaviour intended on your webpage.

Comment: Technically, that's down to the browser implementation. But I doubt any modern browser would do multiple reflows for that particular sample.

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow setting `display:none` does not cause a reflow except in legacy browsers like IE6/7.

Comment: there must be some <html> like a tag whit an id of elem'i' somewhere out there .. not so far .. around .. there... in the corner ... but somehow it's gotta be working. .. if your script is intended to flag 100 possible unique elements in y9ur Document and assign them a 'none' attribute to their 'display' property .. or something like so ... Not a big thing. 100 flags to populate in the document object model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) timeline is a great way to test these kinds of questions, especially since "as horrible as I think it is" is fairly subjective.

I ran a test of the code you posted in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmam1L2f/). Call this **Test 1**.

- *Note that I used 1000 elements, instead of 100, for the test.*

For control, I hid the elements efficiently by setting a wrapper element to `display:'none'` in an animation frame, using the code in *this* [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7nxkpbr/1/). Call this **Test 2**.

- In **Test 1**, rendering took **17.6 milliseconds**.
- In **Test 2**, rendering took **1.5 milliseconds**.

So the empirical answer is yes, the tested code requires more than 10x the computation time to reflow the page layout, versus an alternative (ideal) method. Without knowing more about the code from which it is extracted, it is hard to say whether the method used is appropriate or necessary.

For example, if the elements to be hidden aren't neatly wrapped in their own wrapper `<div>`, optimization is difficult. A strategy that avoids the `for` loop would be to assign the elements a "`hideable`" class, and set up a CSS rule like `wrapper.hideChildren > .hideable { display:none; }`. Then, when we assign class "`hideChildren`" to the wrapper, the marked elements are hidden. [Using this strategy](https://jsfiddle.net/p7nxkpbr/2/), I was only able to get rendering time down to **15ms**, or **10ms** when the wrapper was detached from the DOM before the manipulation, and re-attached afterwards. In other words, the `for` loop may not incur that much of a performance penalty. Bear in mind that 17ms is roughly 1 frame of animation at 60 frames-per-second.

If you examine the screenshots at the end of this post, you will notice that even in **Test 1**, all "scripting" (the execution of the `for`-loop) happens in advance of all "rending" (re-flow). So if your question is, "will the browser alternate scripting and rendering at each iteration of the loop", then the answer is **no**, at least in Chrome 50.

As for fridge_light's link in the comments, the linked documentation never states that setting `display:none` won't trigger a reflow; it just includes a chart from a video that it links to, without a legend. Setting `display:none` *will* change the layout: the height of the document may change, elements flowed beneath the hidden element will be shifted closer to the top of the document, elements inline with the hidden element will shift in-line, floated elements will change position around it, etc. So there is necessarily some computation done by the browser.

Your question is a little confused: the DOM is not necessarily related to page re-flow. Re-sizing the browser window, for example, may trigger a re-flow without affecting the DOM at all! Setting `display` to `none` removes an element from the page layout/flow, but leaves it in the DOM.

### Test 1 [image: Test 1]

### Test 2 [image: Test 3]

Comment: This is a really good answer and, yes, you're right about the linked article and accompanying chart. The author's statement that `From the table above it's clear that not all changes to the style in JavaScript cause a reflow in all browsers` is misleading - the lack of a time for the `display` property means that the test result was less than 1 second, not that no reflow occurred. For what it's worth, the relevant context from the talk itself can be found here at around the 28 minute mark: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJGC0JSlpPE&t=1700

Answer (score 0):

For the code you show, No, it's not

Comment: Huh? The posted code will hide elements, not show them.

Comment: Imagine you have a "<body onload="show();">"
in Which function does exactly the opposite

Comment: This answer / imagination game are not relevant to the OP's question, which pertains to the effect of the code sample on page re-flow.

Comment: A ok. Let me edit the answer to the specific question.

Comment: Can you state the question that you think you are answering? Currently, your answer is just the word "no".